# What is the difference between 'File.read' and 'IO.read'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file, io

I am using Ruby and Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know...

... **what is the difference between**

```
File.read("filename.txt")
```

**and**

```
IO.read("filename.txt")
```

**?**

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> *Editor's note: This answer is out of date. As of Ruby 2.6, File.read is different in that it does not invoke external commands for filenames that start with a "|" character ([issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14245), [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/798316eac260e3cd683da2be23fef53ee64cee00)).*

since File is a subclass of IO and it does not have the read method, when you invoke File.read, you are actually calling IO.read
no difference here.

Comment: Surprisingly no comments here on this old answer. IO.read is not really the same: `IO.read('| whoami') # => "sourav\n"`. But `File.read('| whoami')` raises Errno::ENOENT. So IO.read isn't safe when it comes to reading user given value where security matters. Rubocop also has warning on this.

Comment: @S.Goswami You are right -- since Ruby 2.6, File.read does not invoke external commands ([issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/14245), [commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/798316eac260e3cd683da2be23fef53ee64cee00)).

Answer (score 19):

File is a subclass of IO, and File.read is just IO.read (File class doesn't have this method, so when read gets called IO.read is called).