# Rails 4: how I use the contents of a markdown file in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown

I have a Rails 4 app, and I would like to have a "changes" page that displays the changes introduced in recent versions. I already have this information in a file `CHANGELOG.md` in the root of my project directory. It would be very convenient if I could have a `changes.html.erb` view that converts `CHANGELOG.md` to HTML.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 3640 Apr 24 22:50 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1180 Apr 30 13:58 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 6324 Apr 30 13:58 Gemfile.lock
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  155 Mar 10 14:47 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  249 Mar 10 14:47 Rakefile
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 10 14:47 app/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 10 14:47 bin/
drwxr-xr-x 5 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 24 22:50 config/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  153 Mar 10 14:47 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 31 02:38 db/
drwxr-xr-x 4 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 10 14:47 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 14 13:53 log/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 14 14:01 public/
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr 26 22:44 spring/
drwxr-xr-x 8 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 29 02:58 test/
drwxr-xr-x 6 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 11 23:20 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 3 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Mar 10 14:47 vendor/
```

I was able to follow [this example](https://richonrails.com/articles/rendering-markdown-with-redcarpet) to create a helper method to convert Markdown to HTML using [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet):

**application_helper.rb**

```
require 'redcarpet'

module ApplicationHelper
  # Convert markdown to HTML
  def markdown(text)
    options = {
      filter_html:     true,
      hard_wrap:       true, 
      link_attributes: { rel: 'nofollow', target: "_blank" },
      space_after_headers: true, 
      fenced_code_blocks: true
    }

    extensions = {
      autolink:           true,
      superscript:        true,
      disable_indented_code_blocks: true
    }

    renderer    = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(options)
    @markdown ||= Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
    @markdown.render(text).html_safe
  end    
end
```

I then created a view and action in my static pages controller `pages#changes`.

**changes.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="page-header">Recent Changes</h1>

<div class="row">
  <p>
    <%= markdown("We should be able to render `code` and **bold words** with [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown)") %>
  </p>
</div>
```

This works, but I am not sure how I would instead pass `CHANGELOG.md` to the `markdown` method. It would be nice if I could leave `CHANGELOG.md` in the top level directory, but I suppose I could move it if it would allow me to access it from a view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the contents of a file using `File.read()`. Knowing this, you simply need the path to the file: `Rails.root`/`CHANGELOG.md`

One way of achieving your desired result would be to place the following code in your page's controller, then rendering the markdown in the view:

```
@changelog = File.read("#{Rails.root}/CHANGELOG.md")
```

Then just use `@changelog` with the `markdown` method in the view:

```
<%= markdown @changelog %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use embedded markdown on rails 5+ with gem `emd`

Add this two lines to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'emd'
```

> bundle install.

Then create a view `home/changelog.html.md` and paste your markdown in that file.

> At your route.rb, add this line:

`get '/changelog', to: 'home#changelog'`

> That's all. Visit http://localhost:3000/changelog to see your rendered markdown

Note: you will need a controller called home. `rails generate controller home`

Source: http://github.com/ytbryan/emd

Answer (score 2):

Just add the kramdown-rails gem to your Gemfile and then create .md files in your views directories and it works automatically.  None of the above effort is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You would just read the file from disk.

`Rails.root` gives you a [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) object which points to the root directory of the Rails application.

We then pass the file path to [`IO.read`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/IO.html#method-i-read) which reads the file contents and closes the file handler when its done.

```
<div class="row">
  <p>
    <%= markdown(IO.read(Rails.root.join('CHANGELOG.md')) ) %>
  </p>
</div>
```

However you may want to [use low level caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching) so the conversion is only done when the file changes and not on every request!

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # ...

  def file_to_markdown(file)
    cache_key = [file, File.mtime(file)].join('-')
    Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
      self.markdown(IO.read(file))
    end
  end  
end
```

You would then call it like so:

```
file_to_markdown(Rails.root.join("CHANGELOG.md"))
```

Comment: File.read and IO.read do the exact same thing - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133977/what-is-the-difference-between-file-read-and-io-read